# Lang switcher в placeholder, функциях

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() {
   "use strict";
   var dictionary, set_lang;
   dictionary = {
       "english": {
           "_text1":"This is text1",
           "_text2": "This is text2",
       },
       "russian": {
           "_text1": "Это текст1",
           "_text2": "Это текст2",
       }
   };

   set_lang = function(dictionary) {
       $("[data-translate]").text(function() {
           var key = $(this).data("translate");
           if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               return dictionary[key];
           }
       });
   };
   $("div.select").click(function() {
        var language = $(this).data("lang");
        $(".lang__dropdown").toggle()
        if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(language)) {
           set_lang(dictionary[language]);
       }
   })
   set_lang(dictionary.english);
  
   function test() {
    $("#result").text("Text in function")  // этот текст надо перевести
   } 
   test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-translate="_text1">This is text1</div>
<div data-translate="_text2">This is text2</div>
<br>
<div class="select" data-lang="english">Switch to english(click)</div>
<div class="select" data-lang="russian">Switch to russian(click)</div>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Text in placeholder"> <!--текст в placeholder надо перевести -->
<br><br>
Function test() result:
<div id="result"></div>
```

Собственно есть код для переключения языков. Требуется реализовать так же переключение языка в аттрибуте `placeholder` , а так же в функции `test()`, в сниппете вроде описал.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
   "use strict";
   var dictionary, set_lang;
   dictionary = {
       "english": {
           "_text1":"This is text1",
           "_text2": "This is text2",
           "_result": "Text in function"
       },
       "russian": {
           "_text1": "Это текст1",
           "_text2": "Это текст2",
           "_result": "Текст в функции"
       }
   };

   set_lang = function(dictionary) {
       $("[data-translate]").text(function() {
           var key = $(this).data("translate");
           if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
               return dictionary[key];
           }
       });
   };
   $("div.select").click(function() {
        var language = $(this).data("lang");
        $(".lang__dropdown").toggle()
        if(dictionary.hasOwnProperty(language)) {
           set_lang(dictionary[language]);
       }
   })
   set_lang(dictionary.english);
  
   function test() {
    $("#result").text("Text in function")  // этот текст надо перевести
    set_lang(dictionary.english);
   } 
   test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-translate="_text1">This is text1</div>
<div data-translate="_text2">This is text2</div>
<br>
<div class="select" data-lang="english">Switch to english(click)</div>
<div class="select" data-lang="russian">Switch to russian(click)</div>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Text in placeholder"> <!--текст в placeholder надо перевести -->
<br><br>
Function test() result:
<div id="result" data-translate="_result"></div>
```

Текст в функции решил достаточно просто: так.
Остался атрибут placeholder..